# How does the function "simulate" work, conceptually?

Tags: r, simulate

I apologize in advance if my question seems really simplistic or naive, but I'm trying to understand what the function `simulate` does, conceptually (i.e., I'm interested in the logic of it, independently of whether it's applied to lm, lme, etc.)

Say I'm doing a simple multiple regression on the following data:

```
n <- 40

x1 <- rnorm(n, mean=3, sd=1)

x2 <- rnorm(n, mean=4, sd=1.25)

y <- 2*x1 + 3*x2 + rnorm(n, mean=2, sd=1)

mydata <- data.frame(x1, x2, y)

mod <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=mydata)
```

What does the function `simulate` do when applied to that case? So if I do:

```
simulate(mod, nsim=2)
```

What are the two vectors I obtain?

In essence, is it similar to doing:

```
replicate(2, y + rnorm(n=length(y), mean="some value", sd="some other value"))
```

If it is similar to that logic, then what would "some value" and "some other value" be? Would they be `mean(mod$residuals)` and `sd(mod$residuals)`? Or a permutation of actual residuals? Or something else entirely?

Or is it doing something completely different?

If anyone could explain/confirm how `simulate` works in simple, non-technical terms, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can take a look at the source code using `stats:::simulate.lm`. But since this is more about statistical concepts, I might recommend [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) over Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

It basically does what the help file says: 'Simulate one or more responses from the distribution corresponding to a fitted model object.'

So for each simulation a random draw is taken from the conditional distribution of the outcome variable conditional on the covariates. This conditional distribution is a normal distribution by default in `lm`. The standard deviation of this normal distribution corresponds to the sqrt of MSE of `mod`.

The code below replicates the output (given you use the same seed):

```
set.seed(1)
head(simulate(mod, nsim=2))

set.seed(1)
for(i in 1:nsim) {
  tmp <- predict(mod) + rnorm(length(predict(mod)), 0, summary(mod)$sigma)
  res <- if (i==1) tmp else cbind(res, tmp)
}
head(res)
```

Comment: In the case of `family = 'poisson'` the procedure is the same with rounding to the integer?